# Update json data from a python file

Tags: python, json, firebase

I have a python file which is able to get some data from firebase and put it with a json structure as you can see here:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("firebaseKeyjson")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

#read data
#Getting a Document with a known ID
    
intents = {"intents": []}
results = db.collection('users').document('HtregtuuDDVWglz9DjobFGH9jMo1').collection('chats').get()
for index, result in enumerate(results):
    data = result.to_dict()
    intents["intents"].append({
        "tag": f"firebase data{index}",
        "patterns": [data["message"]],
        "responses": [data["message"]]
    })
print(intents)
```

With this I can get information like this:

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "tag": "firebase data0",
            "patterns": [
                "yop"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "yop"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "firebase data1",
            "patterns": [
                "im well too"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "im well too"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, I can get that data and create a json with that information with this:

```
 with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile: 
     json.dump(intents, outfile)
```

That is perfect, however I usually add some new data to the database, so now I want to update the new data in the json that I already create.
Something like that:

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "tag": "firebase data0",
            "patterns": [
                "yop"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "yop"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "firebase data1",
            "patterns": [
                "im well too"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "im well too"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "NEW DATA UPDATE",
            "patterns": [
                "NEW DATA UPDATE"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "NEW DATA UPDATE"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way?

UPDATE SECTION:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import json
import os

cred = credentials.Certificate("firebasekey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

#read data
#Getting a Document with a known ID
    
intents = {"intents": []}
results = db.collection('users').document('HtregtuuDDVWglz9DjobFGH9jMo1').collection('chats').get()

with open('intents.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for index, result in enumerate(results):
    data = result.to_dict()
    intents["intents"].append({
        "tag": f"firebase data{index}",
        "patterns": [data["message"]],
        "responses": [data["message"]]
    })

#-------with the new part

with open('intents.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

intents = {"intents" : data["intents"]+intents["intents"]} 

with open("intents.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(intents, outfile)
```

and here the ERROR that appear

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\database.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  **File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**
```

Comment: You have to do the same as before, just with the new value of `intents`.

Comment: my problem is that If I add manually data to the jason , when I use that method to update the data that I wrotte before dessapeared, also I cant use intent because the intent depends of the new data of the database so is aleatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

#here you get data information as `intents` as you have done in your code

#now open your sample.json file and load it 

with open('sample.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

#now you have data["intents"]  from json file  and new intents from your db
# the two intents are list of dict . So you can add both obtaining a new list with the elements of the first `intents` and the elements of the second `intents`. 

intents = {"intents" : data["intents"]+intents["intents"]} 

#so now , you can save `intents` as a new json , like before.

with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(intents, outfile)
```

All in one...

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import json
import os

cred = credentials.Certificate("firebasekey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

#read data
#Getting a Document with a known ID
    
intents = {"intents": []}
results = db.collection('users').document('HtregtuuDDVWglz9DjobFGH9jMo1').collection('chats').get()

#---------------------------------------
# don' t need this 
# with open('intents.json') as json_file:
#    data = json.load(json_file)
#----------------------------------------


for index, result in enumerate(results):
    data = result.to_dict()
    intents["intents"].append({
        "tag": f"firebase data{index}",
        "patterns": [data["message"]],
        "responses": [data["message"]]
    })


print("Log intents: ",intents)

#-------with the new part


#First be sure the file exists and it's not empty. At least it must be structured like this: {"intents":[]}

with open('intents.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print("Log data: ",data)

intents = {"intents": data["intents"]+intents["intents"]} 


print("Log new intents: ",intents)


with open("intents.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(intents, outfile)
```

Seems to be ok . But i can't test each parts of the code.
Test it and let me know.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I get some errors, can you check my code in the update section for see if I put like you are tellling me pls

Comment: Let me see the error.  Put it here  on in the update section.

Comment: okey, I already put it the error in the update section

Comment: you do not need  to load  intent.json two times.  Delete the first .